# Law of Total Probability with Conditionals

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

I would greatly appreciate some help on this problem, thank you! It is a past problem, so an answer is acceptable with steps.

Suppose we have a sample space $S$ and two events $A$ and $B$ such that

$$\begin{array}{lcl}S=A\cup B & \text{and} & A\cap B=\emptyset\end{array}$$

and an event $E$,

Suppose we have the following results:

- $P\left(A\right)=1/3$
- $P\left(B\right)=2/3$
- $P\left(E\mid A\right)=1/2$
- $P\left(E\mid B\right)=1/4$

What is $P\left(E\right)\thinspace$?

This is all I know:

$\begin{array}{rcl}
P\left(E\mid A\right) & = & \frac{P\left(A\cap E\right)}{P\left(A\right)}\\
 & =\\
 & = & 1/2
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{rcl}
P\left(E\mid B\right) & = & \frac{P\left(B\cap E\right)}{P\left(B\right)}\\
 & = & 1/4
\end{array}$

**EDIT:**

I figured it out. I was completely overthinking it.

$\begin{array}{rcccl}
P\left(E\mid A\right) & = & 1/2 & = & \frac{P\left(A\cap E\right)}{P\left(A\right)}\\
 & = &  & = & \frac{P\left(A\cap E\right)}{1/3}\\
 & = & P\left(A\cap E\right) & = & 1/6
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{rcccl}
P\left(E\mid B\right) & = & 1/4 & = & \frac{P\left(B\cap E\right)}{P\left(B\right)}\\
 & = &  & = & \frac{P\left(B\cap E\right)}{2/3}\\
 &  & P\left(B\cap E\right) & = & 1/6
\end{array}$

Using the law of total probability,

$P\left(E\right)=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Did you attempt to apply the law of total probability? What happened? You should show some effort by e.g. demonstrating that you've at least looked up the law of total probability and attempted to apply it.

Comment: I am really struggling at understanding the law of total probability. I will update my question with some work I have done.

Comment: The law of total probability is often stated as $P(E) = P(E | A) P(A) + P(E | A^C ) P(A^C)$. In this problem, $A^C = B$, so we have $P(E) = P(E | A) P(A) + P(E | B ) P(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $S = A \cup B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. So $A, B$ are disjoint events whose union is the entire sample space.

Hence we can apply the law of total probability:

$$P(E) = P(A)P(E \mid A) + P(B)P(E \mid B)$$

and all the probabilities on the RHS are known.

Answer (score 0):

Since $S$ is the sample space, then use what you have been told about $S,A,B$ to express this in terms of the provided probabilities.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(E)&=\mathsf P(S\cap E)\\&=\mathsf P((A\cup B)\cap E)\\&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

> $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(E)&=\mathsf P(S\cap E)\\&=\mathsf P((A\cup B)\cap E)\\&=\mathsf P((A\cap E)\cup(B\cap E))\\&=\mathsf P(A\cap E)+\mathsf P(B\cap E)\\&=\mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(E\mid A)+\mathsf P(B)\mathsf P(E\mid B)\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, but I am really struggling with these problems and do not know the next steps. Like I said, it is a past problem, so there is no harm in more details, please.

Comment: $S=A\cup B$ so substitute.  Next use distribution.  Now since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, so too are $A\cap E$ and $B\cap E$.  Therefore....